# Invoking operator[] method from within object

Tags: c++14, operator-keyword

For an implementation

```
template<class T, class C> 
class{
public:
...
T& operator(int)[];
private:
...
void do_something();

};
```

a definition such as

```
template<class T, class C> void Obj<T,C>::do_something(){
 auto some_count = 0;
 ...
 T& tmp = this->[some_count];

 ...
}
```

gets the following compilation error:

> error: expected unqualified-id

Any idea what could be wrong?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: What about `this[...]`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `this` is a pointer to `Obj<T,C>`; that would try to access the pointer as though it were a pointer to an array of `Obj` instead of a single `Obj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `this` is `Obj<T, C>*`. To use it like an instance of `Obj<T, C>`, just use `*this`.

For example,

```
T& tmp = (*this)[some_count];
```

Alternatively, you can use `operator[]` as any other member function:

```
T& tmp = operator[](some_count);
```

But that’s often more confusing, so you should prefer the first format.